# Log request and response to token endpoint in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, access-token

I want to be able to log the request and the response to the token endpoint. For other requests to my api i am using a class inheriting from DelegatingHandler class and override the SendAsync method and register this in Global.asax

Is there a way to log requests and responses to the /token endpoint?

Comment: Same handler can be used to do the logging

Comment: I have added a breakpoint, but it didn't fire. I will check again though.